# Python Orange Distributed Computing

Tags: python, distributed, classification, bayesian, orange

I am currently working with the Python package [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) to run some classification tests on large sets of data. I am primarily using the Naive Bayes method, and I know from other applications that is is able to be distributed out to multiple nodes to compute. Orange unfortunately does not appear to have the ability to use multiple computers or cores.

Has anyone ever used Orange in a cluster environment? or on a multi core computer?

Any suggestions would be helpful..

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using BOINC and their [library](http://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/PyMw) dedicated to such a task.

cheers